# library tex source files in windows

Tags: tikzlibrary

I was trying to use this Tikz example ([Tikz example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/flowchart/)), which needs two library files provided from the same author (tex files as well). The point is that I can't find the path (on Windows) where to put the libraries, and having the latter in the same directory of the source file do not work.
I've been looking for instructions in forums and here on stackexchanger, but I could't find any indication...

Comment: "Package tikz Error: I did not find the tikz library 'positioning-plus'. I looing-plus.code.tex, but neither could be found in the current texmf trees.. \usetikzlibrary{positioning-plus}" ..... The source file of the library is in the same directory of document.tex,I'm sure about that

Comment: the terminal is in the actual folder, I indeed provide the command "pdflatex document.tex"

Comment: I just tested with flowchart.tex tikzlibrarynode-families.code.tex  tikzlibrarypositioning-plus.code.tex all in the same directory and it runs without error in texlive 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the libraries in the folder works. I did not have the  "tikzlibrarynode-families.code.tex" library In the folder, but since the error was about "tikzlibrarypositioning-plus.code.tex" I thought the problem was something else . With both the libraries in the folder it works